# Creating qqPlots based off of two lists in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, quantile

I have two lists with four data frames each. The data frames in the first list ("loc_list_OBS") have only two columns "Year" and "Mean_Precip" while the data frames in the second list ("loc_list_Model") have 33 columns "Year" and then mean precipitation values for 32 different models.

So the data frames in loc_list_OBS look like this but the data goes until Year 2005:

```
Year     Mean_Precip
1965    799.1309
1966    748.0239
1967    619.7572
1968    799.9263
1969    680.9194
1970    766.2304
1971    599.5365
1972    717.8912
1973    739.4901
1974    707.1130
...     ....
2005    ....
```

And the data frames in loc_list_Model look like this but with 32 Model columns total and the data goes to Year 2005 as well:

```
Year   Model 1      Model 2      Model 3    ...... Model 32
1965    714.1101    686.5888    1048.4274
1966    1018.0095    766.9161     514.2700
1967    756.7066    902.2542     906.2877
1968    906.9675    919.5234     647.6630
1969    767.4008    861.1275     700.2612
1970    876.1538    738.8370     664.3342
1971    781.5092    801.2387     743.8965
1972    876.3522    819.4323     675.3022
1973    626.9468    927.0774     696.1884
1974    752.4084    824.7682     835.1566
....    .....       .....         .....
2005    .....       .....         .....
```

Each data frame represents a geographic location, and the two lists have the same four locations but one list is for observed values and the other is for modeled values during the same time frame.

I would like to create qqplots that compare the quantiles of the observed values with the quantiles for each model at each location. I would also like the qqplots from each location on one pdf. I have already written code that compares the modeled data with the standard normal distribution and creates four pdfs as specified above. That code is as follows:

```
for (q in loc_list) local({
  qq_combine_plot <- gather(q, condition, measurement, 2:33, 
                            factor_key = TRUE)
  ggplot(qq_combine_plot, aes(sample = measurement)) +
    facet_wrap(~ condition, scales = "free") +
    stat_qq() +
    stat_qq_line()+
    ggtitle(paste("qqplot for Mean Yearly Precip \n NE 2020-59 RCP45", 
                  names(q)))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    labs(y = "Mean Yearly Precip (mm)")
  ggsave(file=paste("qq_NE_59_s45_", names(q), ".pdf"), 
         device = pdf, height = 14, width = 14)
})
```

I am able to create qqplots that compare the quantiles from the two lists mentioned above, but I can not figure out how to do this with ggplot and still have the same pdf output where the plots are combined and have the appropriate model titles. The code I am using for this is:

```
myfun <- function(x,y)
{
  OBS_Data <- x$Mean_Precip
  for(i in 2:dim(y)[2])
{
    Model_Data <- y[,i]
    qqplot(x=OBS_Data, y=Model_Data, 
           ylab = "Model Quantile Values",
           xlab = "Observed Quantile Values")
  }
}

t.stat <- mapply(FUN = myfun,x=loc_list_OBS,y=loc_list_Model,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Is anyone able to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to compare the data you have in the first list with those of the second list. Then build a `ggplot2` plot that is similar to the `qqplot()` for all of the models. Then make difference between the plots for each city and save the plots (if you have 4 locations you should want four slides in a pdf). Below this context, I suggest next approach using a loop. The steps you included were useful. In order to compare the two dataframes you have to join them after the `gather()` action. The `qqplot()` values can be computed and I included that in the code. This solution is done with `tidyverse` functions so check that you have installed id. The final output will be the pdf but I have created a list (`List`) where plots are stored before being printed. Here the code using dummy lists (created with `df1` and `df2` which are placed at the end of this post) in base of what you shared:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code for data
#Data 1
List1 <- list(u1=df1,u2=df1,u3=df1,u4=df1)
#Data 2
List2 <- list(u1=df2,u2=df2,u3=df2,u4=df2)
```

Now the setting to reach the desired output:

```
#Create an empty list to save the plots
List <- list()
#Loop any of List1 and List2 has the same length
for(i in 1:length(List1))
{
  x <- List1[[i]]
  y <- List2[[i]]
  #Text chain for names
  textchain <- names(List1[i])
  #First reshape data
  qq_combine_plot <- gather(y, condition, measurement, 2:dim(y)[2], 
                            factor_key = TRUE)
  #Now merge with original measure aka mean
  qqmer <- qq_combine_plot %>% left_join(x)
  #Now compute the qqplot measures
  r1 <- qqmer %>%
    group_by(condition) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(qq = map(.x = data, ~as.data.frame(qqplot(x = .$Mean_Precip,
                                                     y = .$measurement, plot.it = FALSE)))) %>% 
    unnest(qq) 
  #Prepare plot
  G <- r1 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~condition,scales = 'free')+
    theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
    ylab("Model Quantile Values")+xlab("Observed Quantile Values")+
    ggtitle(paste0("qqplot for Mean Yearly Precip and modelled values between ",textchain," data"))
  #Assign to list
  List[[i]] <- G
}
```

The loop takes data from both lists and replicate steps in order to sketch the plots and save them in `List`.

Finally, we use another loop to print the plots to pdf. The title of each of them shows the locations based on the names of your lists. In this case, I have set dummy names as `u1,...,u4`:

```
#Export to pdf
pdf('Example.pdf',width = 14)
for(i in c(1:length(List)))
{
  plot(List[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

The final output will be a pdf in some directory you have defined. Just be careful on `facet_wrap()`. You can adjust the number of columns and rows in the plot with the arguments `nrow` and `ncol` that the mentioned function has. Here a little output of the produced pdf:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 
1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 2005L), Mean_Precip = c(799.1309, 
748.0239, 619.7572, 799.9263, 680.9194, 766.2304, 599.5365, 717.8912, 
739.4901, 707.113, 707.113)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(Year = c(1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 
1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 2005L), Model.1 = c(714.1101, 1018.0095, 
756.7066, 906.9675, 767.4008, 876.1538, 781.5092, 876.3522, 626.9468, 
752.4084, 752.4084), Model.2 = c(686.5888, 766.9161, 902.2542, 
919.5234, 861.1275, 738.837, 801.2387, 819.4323, 927.0774, 824.7682, 
824.7682), Model.3 = c(1048.4274, 514.27, 906.2877, 647.663, 
700.2612, 664.3342, 743.8965, 675.3022, 696.1884, 835.1566, 835.1566
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: I have not been able to test this yet, but it looks like it should work! I will mark your answer correct when I do.

Comment: @GarnerKohrell Hi dear! For sure do all checks and let me know how that goes!!!